# How to apply concurrent processing on worker verticles using vert.x

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertxoptions

Vert.x docs mentioning this
:
By default worker verticle instance will only be executed by one thread at any one time (it is not concurrent).

So that means that if I have Verticle with 20 instances e.g:

```
 vertx.deployVerticle(PotEventConsumerVerticle.class.getName(),
                new DeploymentOptions()
                        .setWorker(true)
                        .setInstances(20)
```

I wont be able to get concurrent processing of requests?

how could I concurrent this processing ?
I saw that Multi-threaded worker verticles can be an option but Vert.x doc mention to avoid using this option by all means.

Comment: Using multi-threaded worker verticles is equivalent to using ``executeBlocking`` with ``ordered=false`` (tasks are not queued and can be executed concurrently, if they share state, they will access this state concurrently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deploy 20 instances of a worker verticles, the maximum concurrency will be 20.

Each instance will handle events one after the other, but the 20 instances altogether can handle 20 events in parallel.